# Slow WCF communication due to virusscanner

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, client-server, antivirus

We have a client/server .Net application running on a local network at several clients. The application is using WCF for communicating between the clients and server. We have setup a custom Binding with `binaryMessageEncoding` and compression using `GZip` on net.tcp (port 8733).

```xml
<customBinding>
    <binding name="BinaryCompressionBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                 maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binaryMessageEncoding>
        <tcpTransport transferMode="Streamed"  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" listenBacklog="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

A few months ago (april) several of our clients (not all) started to experience dramatic performance loss due to antivirus scanning. We noticed that during a server call a virusscanner related process became very active for 30-60 seconds (cpu 50-80%).

We have most info on the Cisco AMP for endpoints connector (epsecurityservice.exe).

Disabling the virusscanner will result in the expected performance, but this is not an option. Excluding the client and server application will help, but not always.

Our questions:

- What is causing this, and why didn't it cause any problems before?
- What is the preferred solution?

Comment: As far as I know, the underlying communication over Nettcp binding is controlled by the firewall, whereas HTTP protocol will not be blocked by the firewall or some other anti-virus softwares. In a word, It may be useful to enable inbound and outbound rules for specific ports in a firewall.

Comment: The port 8733 is open in the firewall in- and outbound.